# "try to bleep open your car" why "bleep" can be used in this phrase

Tags: word-usage

> “Imagine trying to **bleep** open your car one day,” says Graham Steel,
>   the boss of Cryptosense, a firm that makes automated security-checking
>   software, “but then you’re told that your car has been locked, and if
>   you want back in you need to send $200 to some shady Russian e-mail
>   address.”

This sentence is extracted from *The economist*. I looked up the dictionary and found that "bleep" can be used as noun or verb. In this sentence, I think "open" is the verb, then "bleep" should be an adverb to modify "open". But there is not such usage in dictionary. Does "bleep" make sense if it is a noun or a verb in this sentence? and how?

The whole paragrah is:

> A recent development is “ransomware”, in which malicious programs
>   encrypt documents and photographs, and a victim must pay to have them
>   restored. “Imagine trying to bleep open your car one day,” says Graham
>   Steel, the boss of Cryptosense, a firm that makes automated
>   security-checking software, “but then you’re told that your car has
>   been locked, and if you want back in you need to send $200 to some
>   shady Russian e-mail address.”

Comment: *bleep open* is more like a compound/phrasal verb. English has a lot of those. Think of those words together as the verb, functioning together as a unit.

Answer (score 18):

At first I thought it might have been an expletive that was deleted.

If the sentence had been

> Your car has been bleeping stolen

I would have interpreted that as a placeholder for a swear word.

But in context it is clear he is talking about a [car remote keyless system](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_keyless_system). Typically these make a bleeping sound indicating that the door was locked/unlocked successfully.

Comment: You should probably mention that, once we understand what “bleep” here refers to, we can see it operating as a part of the compound verb “bleep open,” since the question does ask about it being a noun, verb, or adverb.

Comment: @KRyan GoDuck's answer deserves any credit for that point.

Comment: Yes, and his answer lacks the explanation of what on earth the “bleep” refers to (which I couldn’t figure out until you explained). So neither answer seems complete to me.

Comment: It's not a compound verb: see my comment on GoDuck's answer. I wrote an answer that explains what's going on.

Comment: Even though this is comprehensible, I'm not sure it's standard terminology in the slightest. This is the first I've heard of it. Is this common language?

Comment: @jpmc26 - No doesn't look like it. A Google search finds StackExchange references to this question. When they are excluded not many results at all. The Economist article and a book called "Wedding Night"! https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22bleep+open%22+car+-%22can+be+used+in+this+phrase+%22

Answer (score 10):

In your example, the word **bleep** is as an **onomatopoeia** to signify the sound the car makes when remotely unlocked.  In the same way that a **TV remote** is called a **blipper** (rhymes with flipper).

It could be a **split infinitive**, but may also be the language in transition.

Answer (score 8):

It's **not** a compound verb as others are writing. Compare *sugarcoat* vs. *bleep open* in the following sentences:

> 1a. I tried to bleep open my car.
>
> 1b. I tried to bleep my car open.
>
> 2a. I tried to sugarcoat the scenario.
>
> 2b. *I tried to coat the scenario sugar.

(1b) is perfectly valid, separating the **verb** *bleep* from the **[object complement](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/object_complement.htm) adjective** *open*. Doing the same in (2b), with compound verbs like *sugarcoat*, this is clearly ungrammatical. If *bleep open* were indeed a compound verb, it would behave as a single verb -- an inseparable unit like *sugarcoat* or *tap dance* -- but it does not.

The sentence structure used in the article is the same as in "I tried to force open my car". Again, *force* is the transitive verb and *open* is an object complement.

So what kind of a verb is *bleep*? It's an [onomatopoeia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia) used as a transitive verb. This happens now and then in informal, spoken language. Here's a less grammatically confusing example from Merriam-Webster:

> [[She] keeps *dinging* it into him that the less he smokes the better.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ding)

You could also say something like this:

> He told me my [air horn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_horn) was getting annoying, so I *honked* him away.

Here, that means: I drove him away using some tool (the air horn) that makes a honking sound. Similarly, *bleep* is used in the same sense; the tool being used (the keypad on a remote keyless system) makes a *blip!* sound when you open your car with it.

Comment: Yes that is one valid analysis. But if *bleep open* is taken as a compound verb, then you *cannot* separate it. So your 'proof' has no leg to stand on. In *I tried to finger paint my car*, I can't separate the compound verb *finger paint*. So really it comes down to how one reads *bleep open*, and our answers show that it can be read more than one way.

Comment: I think since "bleep" is being used in a very unusual way here, it _depends_ on being paired with the word "open" for enough context to understand that it was meant onomatopoetically.  Though it sounds akward enough as-is, hearing "I tried to bleep my car open" makes me wonder what perverse things were done to the vehicle.

Answer (score 6):

This is a case of using the *effect* (a noun, in this case the sound) of an action as a verb to describe the action itself.

If you are unfamiliar with the sound heard when unlocking a vehicle, listen to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m15Fr95s7i8&t=3s) for an example of the bleeping sound.

#### Consider other examples such as:

> "I'll buzz you in"

…to describe pressing a button to allow somebody to enter a building — this creates a "buzz"ing sound to indicate to the visitor that the door is now open.

> "I'll ring you"

…to describe contacting somebody via telephone — this causes the recipient's telephone to "ring", alerting the recipient that they have a call incoming.

> "I'll chug a drink"

…to describe consuming a drink — depending how loudly this is done you may hear a "chug" sound from the throat when swallowing.

> "…bleep your car open"

…to describe pressing the "open" button on your keyfob — this causes the car's doors to unlock. To alert you that the car is now locked/unlocked, typically there will be a series of flashes/beeps to indicate that this has happened.

Answer (score 1):

In this case *bleep open* acts like a compound verb, such as the verb *[finger paint](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/finger%20paint)*.

A compound verb is when a noun is "added" to a verb, so that it becomes part of the verb. Other examples are *sugar coat* and *tap dance*. Many times a hyphen is used when spelling these words: this is to show that the noun/verb  compound is being used as **one (compound) word**. And then if they get used a lot  they can be spelled with no hyphen or space (*[breastfeed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/breastfeed)*).

So the author could have written *bleep-open*. But it is probably a fairly recent combination, without a lot of usage, and so people don't  consider it a true compound word yet.

Comment: You should probably mention what the “bleep” here actually is.

Comment: @KRyan The OP is aware that bleep is a noun, and he looked the word up in a dictionary.

Comment: It's **not** a compound verb. *To bleep ... open* is separable, *to sugarcoat* is not. *Bleep* is the verb and *open* is an object complement, as in *try to force open your car*. See my answer for a full explanation.

Comment: @Mauris It's pretty well known that the same sentence can be interpreted in different ways. Thanks for sharing your analysis.